# Would, "Don't run this program," pose a similar problem as, "Don't comply with this imperative"?

Tags: philosophy-of-computer-science, self-reference

I was reading the SEP article on philosophy and computer science and there was [this passage](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computer-science/#SoftHard):

> Suber (1988) goes even further, maintaining that hardware is a kind of software. Software is defined as any pattern that is amenable to being read and executed: once one realizes that all physical objects display patterns, one is forced to accept the conclusion that hardware, as a physical object, is also software. Suber defines a pattern as “any definite structure, not in the narrow sense that requires some recurrence, regularity, or symmetry” (1988, 90) and argues that any such structure can indeed be read and executed: for any definite pattern to which no meaning is associated, it is always possible to conceive a syntax and a semantics giving a meaning, thereby making the pattern an executable program.

Now, take some command, "Don't obey this command," where "this" refers to the self-same injunction. You can't obey it, because obeying it would mean not obeying it. Your failure to obey it can't be taken for a deliberate choice to obey it, then, so although it can be satisfied in a sort of external(?) way, this satisfaction is worthless.

Would, "X: don't run program X," be open to compliance, though? I had thought at first that running an imperative program would mean having an input window, like a command prompt, where you'd type, "Run," and then ENTER, or "X.exe" and then ENTER. So, "Don't run this program," could be obeyed, I thought, by intentionally omitting any sort of input for the relevant prompt. So I thought that there was a gap between imperatives *per se* and imperative programming; but per the quoted section of the SEP article, would even, "Don't obey this command," count as a line of programming?

---

Note: I don't mean to say that the self-countermand is *paradoxical*, or then I would mean to say that if it seemed to generate a paradox, this seeming would be undermined much more transparently than the reasoning that generates the liar paradox might be undermined. So neither do I mean to say that, "Don't run this program," would be paradoxical. But either the imperative or the program *poses a problem*, albeit a simple or even trivial one. Do they both pose the same problem, or do the seemingly slight differences in their compliance-vs.-satisfaction conditions testify against the idea of everything being a program?

Comment: How about the famous book titled, "*Steal This Book*"?

Comment: "*Unauthorized Personnel Only*"

Answer (score 2):

I'll lean on Searle for an answer as that's all that comes to mind, but it might be kind of a non-answer.

> "We as outside homunculi might describe [hammering nails into wood] computationally, and it is often useful to do so. " Searle [1]

(I'm foregoing his larger argument about theory of mind as it's superfluous here)

“Don’t obey this command” is being uttered or written on something. That entire system is a program. Everything is a program/computation in physical monism. The physical instantiation of “don’t obey this command” could have wild semantics such as not taking the utterance or etching of the words literally, just like "is there any salt?" often means "pass the salt". Both Searle and Suber seem to agree that semantics come from us, and they can be attached to any physical system, ad hoc, in diverse and homespun ways.  What is executed by it is up to us to conceive of the desired semantics. A says, “Don’t obey this command”, B: *pats their head and rubs their belly*. A: “Hooray!”. The semantics might be odd, but we must appear very odd to aliens. There is no intrinsic, given computation in this sense. We choose what's actually executed.

We might have a desire for B's above response to be an executed program, and then it just is. Program X prompting "don't execute" is the same, we sit above. We are the homunculi deciding in addition to the raw physics, what semantics and thus computation is executed. The physics doesn't change by us; Program X was run or not (someone typed the initiation command and hit enter or not), and B does something physical in response, even sitting there idly is response. But in either case it's just another physical process, which we can attach meaning to, giving and creating the computation. Two rocks coming together could compute 1+1 or they could not, regardless of the physics. I'm arguing your two cases are physical, ripe for semantics. I don't see "don't obey this command" as abstract, like "is there any salt" isn't either.

With the above, something physical after either case happens. Maybe B doing nothing is obeying it. Is that any weirder of a semantics than what we get up to in other parts of life? If B's next physical whatever, which is inevitable, counts as obeys, doesn't obey, or neither, I argue we can always call that a computation with Suber and Searle's meaning. The answer is there's no problem in either case if we step outside the physics in their sense.

[1] https://philosophy.tamucc.edu/notes/searles-argument

Comment: If you expand the scope of a word to include everything, the word becomes meaningless. Semantics is not infinitely adjustable.

Comment: @ScottRowe Of course we don't want a "god of gaps" type situation where a loaded word/concept is stuffed with everything we don't fully understand. *I'm* hardly expanding it though, I'm only highlighting a connection between Searle, Suber, and OP's question. Searle and Suber are putting semantics in this orientation from what I understand.

Comment: I was responding to you saying: "*Everything is a program/computation in physical monism.*" I earn a living as a Programmer, but I guess *everyone* is.

Comment: @ScottRowe Everyone is a computer right? I mean that's where the modern term originates I think-people's abilities with pen and paper. Water and troughs can be computation, see Maudlin, etc. You're a digital programmer on digital machines, if that maybe helps unload such a single term. Your objection surely contributes and I appreciate it. No desire to undermine your profession.

Answer (score 1):

Or evaluating the truth-value of 'This sentence is a lie'. Or 'Don't think of orange penguins'. From the computers view, it has to run the programme to know what it is, similarly to you having a message that you haven't read. It was easy for you to not think about orange penguins, until the injunction not to. It is in the nature of logic that attention, or Conway's Game of Life iterations, or fluids pushed through [fluidic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidics) circuits, must enact the commands, in order, to determine what they do.

I am interested in thinking about whether that has to be the case. Biology for instance seems to update and execute on the fly.. or does it? You can argue fitness is being evaluated by the output: replication. I'll keep thinking about this. I feel like it relates to how the present moment is in some sense the results of the calculation so far, and the input for future calculations, and this might relate to what appears to be the necessary interface between past and present. Working memory, provides constraints on the complexity of steps..

Universal Constructor Theory suggests hardware capable of building copies of itself, like a 3D printer that can make 3D printers, is fundamentally different to an infinite Turing tape.